# Unity3D + Google Cardboard SDK = No UI masking

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mask, google-cardboard, unity3d-gui

UI mask do not work with Google's Cardboard SDK? It works properly with the Oculus Mobile VR plugin but with the Cardboard SDK the masks seem to be gone.

http://postimg.org/image/b2by7exu9/

This screenshot demonstrates it, outside of the white box we should not see any text.

http://postimg.org/image/ts8wgfu7l/

In editor and with VR Mode disabled it looks fine.

- Did anybody encounter this issue and know how fix?
- In which direction should I investigate further?

I already tried the builds on Note 4 and Galaxy S3 with two different projects just to be sure. Logs didn't show striking lines. I googled and did not found anything related to this issue. Answers and forums the same.

Any suggestions highly appreciated!

Comment: Very odd.I have experienced a lot of issues with Unity UI shaders and transparent shaders in general on Unity 5.0.1 +.
This looks like one of them, does anything flicker?
Please submit the bug to Unity.

Answer (score 0):

While not an answer to your question - I figure after this long any information could be helpful:

I've noticed that the Cardboard SDK in general doesn't play nice with the Unity UI at times. I found that when enabling or disabling VR mode on Cardboard, my UI would cease to respond to touch inputs on other (2D) scenes. I solved this by turning VR mode before changing scenes. So perhaps you need to dig around inside Google's code to see where it's messing with your UI...

Answer (score 0):

have you re-tested with Unity 5.3? there were a bunch of improvements in this area including a re-write of the masking system.

Alternatively, check out the UI Soft Alpha mask component as part of the UI extensions project (https://bitbucket.org/ddreaper/unity-ui-extensions) which is a shader based mask system with Alpha support

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I discovered this still happening in Unity 5.6.0f1 with Google Cardboard.  I was able to fix it by going into the Cardboard SDK settings (PlayerSettings (Android) -> Other Settings -> Virtual Reality SDKs -> Cardboard) and switching the depth format to "24-bit depth | 8-bit stencil" (since the UI mask uses the stencil buffer).  This solved the masking problem for me.